# Gstreamer, unable to render local videos using videomixer

Tags: gstreamer

Using this pipeline I can play two of the same videos using the videomixer, however when I play two different videos it fails.

```
gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink  \
   uridecodebin uri="file:///home/dtolj/projects/test1.mp4" ! decodebin2 ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
   uridecodebin uri="file:///home/dtolj/projects/test2.mp4" ! decodebin2 ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix.
```

error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin1/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin22/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
    Additional debug info:
    qtdemux.c(3865): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin1/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin22/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
    streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated
    ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was decoding the video two times, I removed `decodebin2`, also gstreamer seems very picky about video formats. Maybe I shouldn't rely on `uridecodebin` too much and try to use an appropriate demuxer.